# Copy a CSS class value and generate a new value?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a grid system for my web page layout, much like the [Grid 960 layout](http://960.gs/). I have a bunch of predefined classes for all the grid widths. When I want a `div` to be a certain width, I simply do:

```
<div class="grid_4">
  ...
</div>
```

However, for some of my `div`s I add borders so I created a custom border class that I add to those `div`s for which I want a border.

```
.right-border {
  border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

<div class="grid_4 right-border">
  ....
</div>
```

The problem is that when I add a border, the grid system fails since there isn't enough room across the page to fit all the `div`s (since one of them has a border). I can manually adjust every `div` I add a border to, but I want a cleaner solution since every width of every grid is different (depending on which grid class I use).

Is there a way to get the current `div`s width, and simply subtract 1 for those `div`s that have a class of `right-border`? I'm thinking this is likely only doable with jQuery, but perhaps theres some CSS magic I don't know about that will accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: @AtalShrivastava That feels too imprecise to me. 99% width is variable depending on the `div` width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try border-boxes (if your grid systems doesn't already) so that the width of the element will include the border:

```
[class*="grid_"]{box-sizing:border-box}
```

So that adding a border (or padding) won't affect the computed width of the element -- instead the content area shrinks appropriately.

Comment: Don't forget to add vendor prefixes (-moz, -ms, -o etc).

Comment: Perfect! I knew someone would have some magic that I had not yet learned. Thx.

Comment: You should remove the leading period from `.grid_` within your attribute selector.